# How to make the kline node js command work?

Tags: sockets, dynamic, charts, trading

I try to execute the node kline command, but it gives me an error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\kline'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Although npm install kline was successful. Tell me, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered the kline module doesn't seem to be designed for the command line. Besides this to install a package which should run from the command line, e.g. nodemon, you should add the `-g` flag to the `npm install` command. This will install your package in the global npm scope which also supports calling these packages as a command, if supported.